# Laravel 4 Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links()

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, crud

I tried to implement codes in the book entitled **"[Learning Laravel 4 Application Development](http://www.packtpub.com/learning-laravel-4-application-development/book)"**.

---

A simple use CRUD app as following,

**Controller**

```
    $users = User::all();

    return View::make('users.index', compact('users'));
```

**View**

```
<!--an simple table ...-->
<div class="pagination">
    {{ $users->links() }}
</div>
```

And it shows an error:

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links()`

---

Could someone give me an hint?.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using pagination, so `User::all()` won't work because you are asking Eloquent to return all records without pagination. See [Pagination Usage](http://laravel.com/docs/pagination#usage).

You need to change

```
$users = User::all();
```

to

```
$users = User::paginate(10);
```

Obviously you can change 10 to the number of records per page you want.