# Laravel 6, Method Eloquent\Collections::links does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

Im writing a small program where i want to show all location depending on the current user customer_id.
In this logic customers are company's buying from us so a customer isnt the same as a user. THe customer can have multiple locations and i want to show the locations depending on the current user his customer_id.

To accomplish this i wrote this code:
**This is the code were the error is thrown.**

```
if (isset(auth()->user()->customer_id) && !auth()->user()->hasRole('admin')) {
    $customer = Customer::find(auth()->user()->customer_id);
    $locations = $customer->locations()->get();
} else {
    $locations = Location::all();
}
return view('locations.index', ['locations' => $locations]);
```

I check if the user has a customer_id and isnt a admin. 
If both are true i get the customer connected to the customer_id. 
Then i retrieve all locations related to that customer. 
This all works and when i check it with dd($var) it always returns the expected values.

**index.blade.php**

```
<table id="locations" class="table align-items-center table-flush" style="100%">
                            <thead class="thead-light">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">{{ __('Customer') }}</th>
                                <th scope="col">{{ __('Location Name') }}</th>
                                <th scope="col">{{ __('Address') }}</th>
                                <th scope="col">{{ __('Postal Code') }}</th>
                                <th scope="col">{{ __('City') }}</th>
                                <th scope="col">{{ __('Country') }}</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @foreach ($locations as $location)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $location->customer->name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $location->name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $location->address}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $location->postalcode}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $location->city}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $location->country}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Now when i return the view i get the following error:
`Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist`

The strange thing here is that i already return data with other entities in the same way and that works fine. **This code does the same thing and actually works.**

```
if (isset(auth()->user()->distributor_id) && !auth()->user()->hasRole('admin')) {
    $distributor = Distributor::find(auth()->user()->distributor_id);
    $customer = $distributor->customers()->get();
} else {
    $customer = Customer::all();
}
return view('customers.index', ['customers' => $customer]);
```

After looking around on the internet and SO i found this question:

[Laravel 4 Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24605170/laravel-4-call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-database-eloquent-collectionlink). 
The question looks a lot like mine but the awnser doesnt solve my problem. I have tried to implement their awnser but i still get the same exception.

Can anyone explain why i get this error?

Comment: are you use this variable for pagination?

Comment: add your blade file too. you are using `links` there and that is causing the problem

Comment: No, im just returning the variable to the view and looping through to show the data. Like i said, in the second block of code it works fine.

Comment: @Collin In your `$locations` array any `links` element available?

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya No, there aren't any links elements available

Comment: Can you comment out ```<tr></tr>``` in index just to see if it will error when you are not accessing any properties?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this work

```
$locations = $customer->locations->get();
```

remove parentheses after locations and you need to define function `locations` in your `Customer.php`

```
public function locations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Locations', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: The problem is in the first block of code where i try to retrive all the locations from a specified customer.

Comment: i see then i change my answer, check it again. Thank

Comment: I actually can retrieve the data just fine, when i debug the code i get the expected values. The problem is in the return view part i think.

Comment: Already tried the paginate(). That was the first thing that came to mind. The strange thing is that 2 pieces of code that are the same and do the same dont output the same.

Comment: i saw difference about 2 block code above locations.index & customers.index.
Could you check carefully about 2 blade files, maybe one files using links() somewhere(Ex: in master blade, etc..)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in your template file, you call `links` method for `locations`.
This method is used for pagination implementation. So, you should add `paginate` method to access `links` method.

try this one:

```
$customer = Customer::where('id', auth()->user()->customer_id)->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Still get the same expception, and why would my code with the distributor / customer work and the customer / location code not. I mean its the same code right?

Comment: Can you provide output of dd() for both customers and locations?

Answer (score 0):

you should use
 **paginate($numerOfLocationPerPage)**
 instead of
 **get()**

in $locations = $customer->locations()->get();